# Probability Distributions and their Parameters

Tags: probability-theory

I am looking for the meaning of the Parameter $\lambda$ when it comes to probability distributions like the Poisson and Exponential distributions among other distributions?

Can someone explain? Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the specific probability distribution you are interested in. Some may only have one parameter, others more.

For all distributions, you can express the mean, standard derivation, etc in terms of the parameters, so that the parameter is related to these statistics.

For instance, for the Poisson distribution the mean is just the parameter itself, while for the expontential distribution, the mean is the reciprocal of the parameter.